# Read and write operation in hyperledger fabric smart contract

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I want to discuss some points. Suppose we have an application which requires some validation and we are using node js sdk (as a client for hyperledger) and GOLANG (chaincode). Then, where should we apply this validation which is dependent on blockchain data? As per my knowledge we can apply in 2 places:

1. Node js sdk after fetching data from blockchain.
2. We can also apply validation in chaincode itself.

So which approach should be followed and why any suggestion on the same.

One More point I have read out in an article on medium that we should keep the read and write operation minimum as possible in a transaction initiated for blockchain(Means too much read write inside the chaincode).

So please provide your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 1):

That is really good point to think upon, if we do validation at chaincode level then chaincode will become complex and may be take more time to execute/invoke the transaction but if we go for sdk level validation then network bandwidth & network performance impacted can be impacted.

At which level we should perform validation should be depend on which kind of transaction we are performing after validation i.e suppose if read transaction then I would prefer do the validation at chaincode level and if  write transaction then SDK level because this will improve application performance.This is my thiking and I would do like that way

Comment: any of the party can change their sdk source code as they are aware with the chaincode logic  and can malformed the data .So In this situation what is your opinion ? @kamlesh

Comment: yes that thing also need to be consider , you are right then chaincode level validation is better approach

Answer (score 0):

Here a good article about Hyperledger Fabric performances.

https://www.ibm.com/blogs/blockchain/2019/01/answering-your-questions-on-hyperledger-fabric-performance-and-scale/